# Accidentally remote-locked my device, now I get a black screen only

Tags: lock-screens, locked-out

I just purchased an Android mobile device, and was exploring its great features! I mistakenly activated the Google *Android Device Manager* found on my phone just to feel how it works.

Meanwhile, I realised I've done wrong enabling the remote lock when I later got my device rebooted! Phone was on, but all I get is a black screen. I cannot unlock or perform any operation as there are no optional suggestions provided to get it unlocked or deactivated  by the user.

What can I do to access my device again?

Comment: Please consider explaining your issue better.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure I understand you correctly, but I assume that you have accidentally locked your phone using the `Android Device Manager`.

I suggest you try these steps:

- Open [Android Device Manager](https://www.google.com/android/devicemanager) website.
- Login to the same Google Account set up on your Locked Device.
- Select your locked device on the website.
- Explore the 'Device Lock' options and unlock from there.

Answer (score 2):

If [Sheharyars answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/81962/16575) doesn't work out:

1. Boot to recovery-menu. How to do it depends on your device, which you didn't specify; usually it's done by powering it off, then holding the <kbd>Vol down</kbd> and <kbd>Power</kbd> buttons at the same time for a couple of seconds, until the recovery menu appears.
2. In the recovery menu, select [factory-reset](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/factory-reset/info) (sometimes labeled "Reset to factory defaults" or similar). This will wipe all user data (including settings and the apps you've installed) from the device, and thus also your preferences for the lock.

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't used android Device Manager and A third party app like AVG then boot in through safe mode. With this mode all third party apps will stop functioning and only system apps will be running. The. Go to app manager in setting as open the app info which has blocked you out and press Clear Data Button.